# Filter Collections using iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a template rendering my Collection using `{{#each Collection}}`, I'm using iron-router to route this template like this:

```
Router.route('/home', function () {
this.render('home');
this.layout('header');
});
```

how can i use a "books" filter button so iron-router apply that filter to the subscription so i can only see the filtered version of my Collection like the following:

```
Collection.find({category: "books"});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach this but one simple way would be to define a sub-route that takes a category as a parameter:

```
Router.route('/collections/:category',{
  name: 'collections',
  layoutTemplate: 'header',
  data(){
    return Collections.find({category: this.params.category});
  }
});
```

Then your button code can just do `Router.go('/collections/books')` but you can now have multiple buttons each tied to different categories.

Comment: Your answer seems to be promising, however it didn't work for me. maybe its because there was a misunderstanding  about "collections" template, so i changed the name to "home".

Comment: `name` should be the name of the template you want to load on the route. If you have a `layoutTemplate` then that template must include a `{{> yield}}` to insert the route template.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#organizing-subscriptions you can manage your subscription in Template and not in the route. So you can do:

```
import {ReactiveDict} from 'meteor/reactive-dict';
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';

Template.home.onCreated(function(){
  var that = this;
  that.state = new ReactiveDict();
  //that.state.set('selected-category',YOUR_DEFAULT_CATEGORY);
  that.autorun(function(){
    that.subscribe('subscription-name',that.state.get('selected-category'));
  });
});

Template.home.events({
  'click .js-category':function(e,tpl){
    let category = tpl.$(e.currentTarget).data('category');
    tpl.state.set('selected-category',category); 
  }
});
```

And in your Template:

```
<button type="button" data-category="books" class="js-category">Books</button>
```

Hope this will help you to find the right solution for your